# Android Material Chip Theme overriding

Tags: android, material-design, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

I want to customize a Material chip.

I would think this is how to do it:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">

    .... lots more theme stuff here

    <item name="chipStyle">@style/MaterialChips</item>
    <item name="chipGroupStyle">@style/MaterialChips</item>
    <item name="chipStandaloneStyle">@style/MaterialChips</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialChips" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/chips</item>
</style>
```

None of the tags like `chipStyle` affect the chips. But if I set `app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chips"` in xml it works.

It also works fine like this for other things like say `<item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>`.

The material documentation (if you can call it that) is really not helping.

Comment: The style is defined by the `chipStyle` attribute. It works. How do you define the Chip in the layout?

Comment: I'm guessing you suspected something like this. I had ```style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"``` set on the chips... I feel silly. Thank you for getting me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app theme is correct.

The **default style** used by [`Chip`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md) component is defined in the app theme by the **`chipStyle`** [attribute](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0-beta02/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip.java#L186).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
  <!-- Default style for chip component -->
  <item name="chipStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action</item>  
</style>
```

You can customize this style using for example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
  <!-- Default value for chipStyle -->
  <item name="chipStyle">@style/MaterialChips</item>  
</style>

<style name="MaterialChips" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/chips</item>
</style>
```

If you specify the `style` attribute in your layout, this style **overrides** the default value.

```
        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
            .../>
```

In this case the Chip uses the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry` style.

Comment: your link taught me how to find answer for the same question about other android views. thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

if you define chip style in layout xml, chip override your theme.
It may work if you clear chip style in layout xml.